# Simplify/Show Boolean Logic expression is a Tautology

Tags: logic

I need to prove that the expression $(p\leftrightarrow q) \wedge (q\leftrightarrow r) \rightarrow (p\leftrightarrow r) $ is a tautology, I have managed to simplify it down to
the expression $pr+p'r'+pq'+p'q+rq'+r'q$ or alternatively $(p\land r)\lor(\lnot p\land \lnot r) \lor (p\land \lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\land q)\lor(r\land \lnot q)\lor(\lnot r\land q) $ . But I haven't been able to show that it is a tautology without using a truth table. How can I simplify it further?

Comment: What do the dashes in the superscript mean?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, they mean complement. I'll edit it to remove the dashes from the last expression

Comment: Why don't you use the table of truth?

Comment: I agree. I tried simplifying it. But that probably just makes it more difficult or complex.

Comment: I verified it using a truth table but I just want to try and prove it without a truth table

Comment: Isn't :
$$(p \leftrightarrow q) \equiv [(p \wedge q) \vee (\lnot p \wedge \lnot q)]$$

Comment: @Essaidi yes that is correct

Comment: Because in your answer you wrote :
$$(p \leftrightarrow q) \equiv [(p \wedge q) \vee (\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (\lnot p \wedge q)]$$

Comment: No I only wrote the simplified expression, not just the  expansion for $(p↔q)$

Comment: Ok, sorry. We can try these two steps :
1. Show that : 
 $$(p \leftrightarrow q) \leftrightarrow [(p \rightarrow  q) \wedge (q \rightarrow p)]$$
2. Show that :
$$[(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (q \rightarrow  r)] \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)]$$

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $p = p1 = p(q+q')=pq+pq'$

We can use this to 'split' all your $6$ terms:

$pr+p'r'+pq'+p'q+rq'+r'q=$

$prq+prq'+p'r'q+p'r'q'+pq'r+pq'r'+p'qr+p'qr'+rq'p+rq'p'+r'qp+r'qp'$

Reorder each term alphabetically:

$pqr+pq'r+p'qr'+p'q'r'+pq'r+pq'r'+p'qr+p'qr'+pq'r+p'q'r+pqr'+p'qr'$

And reorder the 12 terms:

$pqr+pqr'+pq'r+pq'r+pq'r+pq'r'+p'qr+p'qr'+p'qr'+p'qr'+p'q'r+p'q'r'$

Remove duplicates:

$pqr+pqr'+pq'r+pq'r'+p'qr+p'qr'+p'q'r+p'q'r'$

And put them back together:

$$pqr+pqr'+pq'r+pq'r'+p'qr+p'qr'+p'q'r+p'q'r'=$$

$$pq+pq'+p'q+p'q'=$$

$$p+p'=$$

$$1$$